# Opengl premultiplied alpha image render process

Tags: opengl, premultiplied-alpha

I'v been learning OpenGL2.0 rendering stuffs for a while and here are some personal understanding on alpha rendering I want to know if they are right:

Say I have a PNG (32 bit) file (none premultiplied alpha image) with only one pixel (src image)

```
PNG                                                 Shader - glFragColor        GPU - SRC_ALPHA           SRC_ONE
(255, 0, 0, 255) - red / none transparent           (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)        (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)      (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
(255, 0, 0, 128) - red / half transparent           (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5)        (0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.75)     (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
(128, 0, 0, 255) - drak red / none transparent      (0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)        (0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)      (0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
(128, 0, 0, 128) - drak red / half transparent      (0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5)        (0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.75)    (0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Here are four examples and 4 columns for each.
Take row NO.2 for example:

```
1. The PNG image is red but half transparent so the rgba should be (255, 0, 0, 128)
2. The texture info is passed to frag shader and the value for glFragColor shoud be (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5)
3. When rendering the src color to GPU OpenGL will try to bend it with the dst color
4. let's say the dst color is (0, 0, 0, 255) and blend func for dst is GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA
5. if the blend func for dst is GL_SRC_ALPHA, the final pixel rendered will be (0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.75)
6. if the blend func for dst is GL_ONE, the final pixel rendered will be (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

The result for (6) is definitely wrong since the transparency lost while the result for (5) should be good.

And that's why I should use GL_SRC_ALPHA for none premultiplied alpha image and GL_ONE for premultiplied alpha image.

Comment: Err, what? Bullet points **(5)** and **(6)** should be about the src blend factor. The dst factor remains 1-SrcAlpha regardless.

Comment: Can you clarify what you think are src and dst? Your explanation leads me to believe you may be confused; src is the output from the fragment shader and dst is what is already in the framebuffer.

Comment: My understanding is: the program first load the PNG and convert it to texture, than the texture info is passed to v&&f shaders and the output of the frag shader should be the "src" (in my case), then the "src" will be blended with "dst" (the stuffs in the frame buffer), and finally the output is what I see in my screen ~